# Combining case timeline with case sequence(s)

Tags: civicase

Our organization would like to record all activities for coaching processes with clients. In order to accomplish this I consider using Civicase.

The case could comprise following:

Activities on the case timeline e.g.:

- A. open case
- B. send intake form (receive intake form / evaluate and/or process intake form)
- C. initial coach/intake session
- D. Coaching session(s)
- E. send evaluation form (receive evaluation form / evaluate and/or process evaluation form)
- F. close case

Because we wouldn't know the exact number of required coach sessions (D) at the time the case is initiated, I guess activity D (Coach sessions) could/should initiate a Sequence (of coach sessions).
Would this be a good approach or should this be done differently?

A second question:
Should we assign a coaching process case to a coach and/or should we add a case role 'coach' and assign the coach there?

Many thanks for your kind input.